# Truncating a large csv-file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file which is too large to completely fit into my laptop's memory (about 10GB). Is there a way to truncate the file such that only the first n entries are saved in a new file? I started by trying

```
df = pandas.read_csv("path/data.csv").as_matrix()
```

but this doesn´t work since the memory is too small.

Any help will be appreciated!

Leon

Comment: You can use the chunksize parameter of read_csv to read the file in chunks. This should allow to read in the file in smaller parts at a time. The awnser to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas) demonstrates it's use

Answer (score 4):

Use `nrows`:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("path/data.csv", nrows=1000)
```

The [`nrows` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) say:

> Number of rows of file to read. Useful for reading pieces of large files

Comment: thank you, this works! Now I only have the problem that my table contains both numbers and strings, and all the strings are replaced with nan. Do you know a fix for that?